# HTTPpost from android to MySQL database in a AsyncTask

Tags: android

I'am trying to send some data from my android device to a `MySQL database`. It seems that the database doesnt get update, and the `ProgressDialog` in my `AsyncTask` doesn't finish.

**So here is my PHP script**

```
 <?php 
   mysql_connect("localhost","$username","$password") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("databaseName");

   $pcn =   $_POST['PCN'];
   $date = $_POST['Date'] ;

   $query_add="INSERT INTO data (`pcn`,`date`) VALUES ('$pcn','$date')";
   $query_exec=mysql_query($query_add) or die(mysql_error()); 
   mysql_close()
 ?>
```

**Then my java code:**

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
      progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(context,"Please Wait..","Sending data to database",false);
    }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


      try {
          httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/index.php");
          ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PCN", pcn));
          postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", date));

          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));                   
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
          Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error:  "+e.toString());
       }  

    return "";
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        progressDialog.dismiss(); 
        Toast.makeText(context, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

}
```

**In my Manifest file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

**This is the output from LogCat**

```
07-04 12:52:34.025: E/SendToServer(15167): Error:  org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused
```

I've read several places that I cant use `http://localhost`, but when I try `http://10.0.0.2` it should work.

I cant figure out how to do this, can anybody point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

When I try `10.0.2.2` instead of `Localhost` LogCat outputs this:

```
Error:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=10.0.2.2
```

**UPDATE 2**

Now when I use `http://10.0.2.2` the `progressdialog` never finish, logcat is not showing me any exceptions either

**UPDATE 3**

I think I know why my app doesn't update my database. My phone is in another wireless network than my workstation..

Comment: So, have you tried using `http://10.0.0.2/` or not? That should do it...

Comment: The output from LogCat is the same?

Comment: @silentw - Its a 10.0.2.2 not 10.0.0.2 :-)

Comment: @user370305 yes, it was an typo :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line,

```
httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/index.php");
```

Android doesn't understand localhost in url.

Instead of **localhost** either use the **Static IP** of your system or **10.0.2.2**.

Comment: Now, check your response from the server. Debug the code of doInBackground.

Answer (score 0):

Android don't use **localhost**, try **10.0.2.2**

More details in [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Comment: Is there something different in my answer?

Comment: I start writing but stopped due to work, when I submitted it your answer was allready there.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting when using "10.0.2.2" most commonly occurs when you are using `10.0.0.2` while you must use `http://10.0.2.2`.

Make sure you are using:

```
httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/index.php");
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I currently uses this approach, but my progressDialog doesn't finish, it seems that the android app doesn't get finshed posting data to my database..